# Passing a value from PHP script to Perl CGI, the simplest way wanted

Tags: php, perl

Everyone, how are you there?

I want to send a value from a PHP page by Form Action to a CGI script written in Perl.  The method is either POST or GET, it doesn’t matter.  I want to do it as simplest as possible.  Is there any way without using CGI module?  Or one must use CGI module?

Here is my trial without using CGI module.  Please give me comments or feedback to help me around.    Thanks, thanks, everyone.

```
 <?php
 $musician_fn = $_POST[‘musician_fn’];

 echo <<<END
 <form action=“URL_PATH/cgi_01.pl method=“POST”>
 <select name=“musician_fn”>
 <option value=“name1”> Name1 </option>
 <option value=“name2”> Name2 </option>
 …
 </select>
 <input type=“submit” Value=“Go”>
 </form>

 END;
 ?>
```

Now, CGI in Perl.

```
 #! /use/bin/perl -w

 $musician_fn = $FORM{musician_fn};

 print “$musician_fn”;
```

Unfortunately, this way doesn’t work.

Another CGI by using CGI module, which I used to use.

```
 #! /use/bin/Perl -w

 Use CGI qw(:standard);

 $musician_fn = param(“musician_fn”);

 print “$musian_fn”;
```

This code worked before in Perl 5.8.8, but not in Perl 5.36.0.   How should I fix?  Thanks,thanks,everyone.

Any idea to fix the bug.

Comment: You forgot to output a header (which is necessary for all CGI scripts, even when using Perl 5.8)

Comment: `“` and `"` are not the same thing.

Comment: Hi !   ikegami-san   thanks.   ありがとう。　I just skipped a header for output to make it simpler.   Sorry about it.   Now on I will write a header next time.   By the way, regarding double quotes, you are also very careful.   Thanks.   I will pay careful attention too.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be syntax errors in both your php and perl.
Note the quotes are plain quotes.
many will say not to use CGI but going with what you asked:
These two files can talk to each other:

```
     <?php
     $musician_fn = $_POST[‘musician_fn’];
    
     echo <<<END
     <form action="getPhp.pl" method="POST">
     <select name="musician_fn">
     <option value="Miles Davis"> Miles Davis </option>
     <option value="Prince"> Prince </option>
     </select>
     <button type="submit"> Go </button>
     </form>
    
     END;
     ?>
```

Note I call this file getPhp.pl

```
    #! /usr/bin/env perl
    use warnings;
    use strict;
    
    use CGI::Carp; # send errors to the browser, not to the logfile
    use CGI;
    
    my $cgi = CGI->new(); # create new CGI object
    
    my $musian_fn = $cgi->param('musician_fn');
    
    print $cgi->header('text/html');
    
    if ($musian_fn){
        print "Musician: $musian_fn";
    }
    else {
        print "Musician not found";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks turtle, it looks nice about your code.   I will check it soon.   And get back to you.   By the way, how do I confirm CGI module is already loaded or not ?    Is there any difference between CGI.pm module vs. CGI module ?

Comment: Are you asking about the Apache cgi module? If the Apache cgi module is not loded / configured you'll see the perl source code when you load the page. You can check it from the cmd line  " apache2ctl -M | grep 'cgi " Perl will throw an error if its CGI module does not load.

Comment: Sorry it took too long time.   I am still on the way to test your codes above.    Before that, I ran the following codes, and it worked.   Posted on the code section.

Comment: Hi !  Everyone there !   I used to test Perl codes at directly /home/mkido/bin on whichever LINUX around me, without uploading to the WEB-server.   This way of  test only work at the Perl CGI with [#! /usr/bin/perl -w  ] as the first line of salutation.   Now, I saw Tutle's code uses the first line of salutaion as [#! /usr/bin/env perl].     I saw the difference between [perl -w] vs. [env perl].   Are they very different in its function???   Let's me know if [#! /usr/bin/env perl] is the popular way of salutation nowadays?   So that I will adjust most of my codes to [env perl] way.

Answer (score 0):

I got it by the way of using CGI module in Perl.   CGI module was loaded by my administrator by cpan according to him.

HERE is PHP part

```
<php?
echo <<<END
<form action="http://110.3.33.130/cgi-bin/cgi61_us15.pl">
<table width="500" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">

<tr>
<td width="200"><b>BY NAME alternative </b></td>
<td>
<select name="musician_fn">
<option selected> Scroll down please.
<option value="bangles">                                  Bangles, The                                                                        </option>
<option value="10_000_maniacs">                           10,000 Maniacs                                                                      </option>
<option value="112_group">                                112                                                                                 </option>
<option value="2pac">                                     2Pac                                                                                </option>
<option value="2_unlimited">                              2 Unlimited                                                                         </option>
 </select>
 <input type="submit" value="Go">
 </form>
</td></tr>
</table>
END;
?>
```

======================================

And here is the Perl part.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
use CGI qw(:standard); 
$musician_fn = param("musician_fn");
```

This way did the good capture of a variable from PHP to Perl_CGI.

======================================

Here is on my way to turtle code, at fist PHP code, named turtle_cgi.php

```
<html>

<a href="http://my_serverIP/cgi-bin/turtle_cgi.pl"> link </a>

LET me see.

</html>
```

=================
And here is turcle_cgi.pl (on my way to turtle codes)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;

my $q = CGI->new;
print $q->header();
print "OK";
```

It worked by calling from WEB-caster.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).